# 4 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, game-development

Getting the following below error when i try to build the game. it was exported from unity.

```
duplicate symbol '__RemoveAllDeliveredNotifications' in:
/Users/ompatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone- 
fmncsstqpmnraxdmfvyxydxwcvuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity- 
iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-n 
ormal/armv7/UnityNotificationWrapper.o
/Users/ompatel/Downloads/IOS_Build/Libraries/EasyMobile/Plugins/iOS/libEasyMobile.a(Notifications.o)

 duplicate symbol '__ScheduleLocalNotification' in:
/Users/ompatel/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone- 
fmncsstqpmnraxdmfvyxydxwcvuc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Unity- 
iPhone/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Unity-iPhone.build/Release-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects- 
normal/armv7/UnityNotificationWrapper.o
/Users/ompatel/Downloads/IOS_Build/Libraries/EasyMobile/Plugins/iOS/libEasyMobile.a(Notifications.o)
```

Comment: Go to your Build Phases and search for UnityNotificationWrapper file , delete the multiple instances of the file .

Comment: Remove your Xcode derived data, clean your project and build it again.

Comment: @Help there is no multiple instance of UnityNotificationWrapper file

Comment: @iMuzahid still the error comes after doing what you said